# How to make a keypress trigger a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make code where a button press will activate a a href link. This is the code I have.

**HTML :**

```
<a id="#next" href="talonbragg.com">↵</a>
<a id="#previous" href="talonbragg.com">↳</a>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.onkeydown = function() 
    {
        var j = event.keyIdentifier
        if (j == "Right")
            window.location = nextUrl
        else if (j == "Left")
            window.location = prevUrl            
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var nextPage = $("#next")
    var prevPage = $("#previous")
    nextUrl = nextPage.attr("href")
    prevUrl = prevPage.attr("href")
});
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same `id`. Fix your HTML first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way to do it. 
You can find key codes in the link @BestBudds provide.

I've updated your code like this :

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37: // left
      var href = $('#previous').attr('href');
      window.location.href = href;
      break;

    case 39: // right
      var href = $('#next').attr('href');
      window.location.href = href;
      break;
  }
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="#next" href="http://google.com">↵</a>
<a id="#previous" href="http://stackoverflow.com">↳</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> First of all **DON'T USE** **[`keyIdentifier`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyIdentifier)** it's a **'Non-standard'** AND **'Deprecated'** property.

Since you're using jQuery you could use `e.keyCode || e.which` in the on `keydown` event like :

```
$('body').on('keydown', function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if(code==39)
      $('#next').click();
    else if(code==37)
      $('#previous').click();
})
```

And simply click the related anchor.

**NOTE :** You should remove the `#` from your `id`'s, so it will be like :

```
<a id="next" href="talonbragg.com">↵</a>
<a id="previous" href="talonbragg.com">↳</a>
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('keydown', function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if(code==39){
      $('#next').click();
    }else if(code==37){
      $('#previous').click();
    }
  })

  //This part just for debug purpose
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log($(this).attr('id')+' Clicked');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="next" href="talonbragg.com">↵</a>
<a id="previous" href="talonbragg.com">↳</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it different way:

```
$('body').keypress(function(event) {
                var nextUrl = $('#next').attr('href');
                var previousUrl = $('#previous').attr('href');
                var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                var left = 37;
                var right = 39;
                if (key == left) {
                     window.location = previousUrl;
                }else if(key == right){
                     window.location = nextUrl;
                }else{return false;}

            });
```

Now this is saying on keypress when is body focused of your website the event will find keycode from pressed key from keyboard.

You can find key codes [here](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

After that you just need to do something if correct key was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '27') {
        window.open("https://www.tradezone.fr", target="_self");
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '121') {
        window.open("https://www.tradezone.tv", target="_self");
    }
}
```